# Cell event in Nattable

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp, nattable

I am new to Nebula Nat table, I have successfully created nattable in my application.

i have several columns one among them, one among them has a combo in it. i want to trigger a listener when ever there is change in the value of the cell . for example if i my combo box has value A and B. if change the value to A to B. i want to trigger a event and based on that event i want to change the value in the another cell.

I tired some of the listener nothing is comfortable, **is there any listener in Nattable specific to cell**. Because what ever the listener we have all specific nat table as a whole.

I analyzed more i found out that i can do capture selection in the cell using **CellSelectionEvent**. But what i need is to trigger whenever there is a change in the cell. but **CellSelectionEvent** triggers at the time of selection. **Is there event i can use  whenever there is a change in the cell.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With NatTable 1.6 the `DataUpdateEvent` was introduced for this.

Comment: Hi Sir, thanks. now i am able to trigger event after change in the data.